# Jquery droppable on image map areas

Tags: jquery

I have an image using an image map, and I would like to set up drag 
and drop so that I know what section of the image the item was dropped 
on to.

It sort of works, but when I drop an item onto one of the areas, it 
triggers the function for all of the areas.  Is there a way to get 
that to work?

Please help...

Comment: You should provide an example how you implemented it, which would make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

So, this is an old question but it is a problem that I encountered myself this week and couldn't find any helpful answers for. The answer above doesn't quite directly address the issue of making a droppable from an area element on an html image map - it posits an answer but that answer doesn't actually work because making an 'area' droppable makes the entire image map into the droppable so you can't determine which area is active when the item is dropped.

Here is the solution that I ended up implementing for my problem (which uses poly areas):

```
<div id="content">
<div id="targetImage"><img src="images/interactive_bg_triColored.png" usemap="#targetOverlay" alt="Strategic Action Chart"/>
    <map id="targetOverlay" name="targetOverlay">
    <area id="slice_0" shape="poly" coords="47, 294, 82, 178, 236, 267, 224, 293" />
    <area id="slice_1"  shape="poly" coords="87, 171, 168, 89, 258, 235, 240, 254" />
    <area id="slice_2"  shape="poly" coords="177, 82, 295, 48, 297, 228, 265, 234" />
    <area id="slice_3"  shape="poly" coords="302, 49, 419, 81, 334, 232, 303, 227" />
    <area id="slice_4" shape="poly" coords="428, 84, 514, 170, 360, 258, 338, 239" />
    <area id="slice_5" shape="poly" coords="364, 266, 516, 186, 546, 292, 373, 294" />
    <area id="slice_6" shape="poly" coords="546, 307, 518, 412, 363, 333, 373, 305" />
    <area id="slice_7" shape="poly" coords="512, 427, 428, 508, 340, 361, 360, 343" />
    <area id="slice_8" shape="poly" coords="421, 515, 304, 549, 302, 375, 334, 365" />
    <area id="slice_9" shape="poly" coords="295, 550, 180, 517, 266, 366, 295, 371" />
    <area id="slice_10" shape="poly" coords="170, 512, 86, 431, 240, 340, 259, 360" />
    <area id="slice_11" shape="poly" coords="80, 422, 51, 304, 228, 305, 235, 332" />
    </map>
</div>
<div id="word_list">
    <div id="instructions">Drag these action words into the appropriate category on the left.</div>
    <div id="word_6" class="draggable_word answer_o">Adjust</div>
    <div id="word_7" class="draggable_word answer_m">Infer</div>
    <div id="word_8" class="draggable_word answer_m">Synthesize</div>
    <div id="word_4" class="draggable_word answer_o">Summarize</div>
    <div id="word_5" class="draggable_word answer_o">Maintain<br /> Fluency</div>
    <div id="word_9" class="draggable_word answer_m">Make<br />Connections</div>
    <div id="word_11" class="draggable_word answer_p">Critique</div>
    <div id="word_10" class="draggable_word answer_m">Predict</div>
    <div id="word_2" class="draggable_word answer_o">Monitor <br />and Correct</div>
    <div id="word_3" class="draggable_word answer_o">Search & Use<br /> Information</div>
    <div id="word_0" class="draggable_word answer_p">Analyze</div>
    <div id="word_1" class="draggable_word answer_o">Solve Words</div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .draggable_word 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block
}

.draggable_word:hover 
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Note, you have to have a width set on your .draggable class (you can name it whatever, but it needs to be applied to the item you are going to make draggable, in my case a div that has a small amount of text inside it)

```
var x1, y1 = 0;
var area = []; //set of area objects
var myDropTarget = 'invalid';

$(document).ready(function () {
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    $('#word_' + i).draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        revert: function (socketObj) {
            //if false then no droppable target was found
            if (socketObj === false) {
                //revert the draggable by returning true
                return true;
            }
            else { //the drop location was a droppable zone, now test it for answer validity

                var offset = $(this).offset(); //gets the x,y position of the dragged object when it stops
                x1 = offset.left + ($(this).width() / 2); //establishes the center of the object to use for testing x,y
                y1 = offset.top + ($(this).height() / 2);

                var result = dropTarget(x1, y1); //returns id of area or 'invalid'
                //logic to validate answers
                if (result === 'invalid') {
                    return true;
                } else { //evaluate for answer correctness
                    var testSlice = result.split('_');

                    if ((testSlice[1] > -1) && testSlice[1] < 6) { //first 6 slices are 'orange'
                        if ($(this).hasClass('answer_o')) { //correct answer
                            return false; //slice matches word answer class so do NOT revert
                        }
                    } else if ((testSlice[1] > 5) && testSlice[1] < 10) { //next 4 slices are 'maroon'
                        if ($(this).hasClass('answer_m')) { //correct answer
                            return false; //slice matches word answer class so do NOT revert
                        }
                    } else if ((testSlice[1] > 9 ) && testSlice[1] < 12) { //last 2 slices are 'purple'
                        if ($(this).hasClass('answer_p')) { //correct answer
                            return false; //slice matches word answer class so do NOT revert
                        }
                    }  else return true;


                }

                console.log('drop ' + x1 + ', ' + y1);
                console.log(result);

                //if no correct answer was found then it will still need to revert;
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}

$('map area').each(function (i) {
    //this creates an array of area polygon objects so that we can test when an item has been dropped inside of one
    area[i] = {}; // creates a new object which will have properties for id, x coordinates, and y coordinates
    area[i].id = $(this).attr("id");
    area[i].x = [];
    area[i].y = [];
    var coords = JSON.parse('[' + $(this).attr("coords") + ']');
    var totalPairs = coords.length / 2;
    var coordCounter = 0; //variable to double iterate
    for (ix = 0; ix < totalPairs; ix++) { //fill arrays of x/y coordinates for pnpoly
        area[i].x[ix] = coords[coordCounter];
        area[i].y[ix] = coords[coordCounter + 1];
        coordCounter += 2;
    }
});

$('#targetImage').droppable({
    // maps or areas don't work well as droppable targets so we make image's container div into the droppable 
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
});


function dropTarget(dropX, dropY) {
var target = 'invalid';

for (i = 0; i < area.length; i++) { //iterate through all of our area objects
    if (pnpoly(area[i].x.length, area[i].x, area[i].y, dropX, dropY)) {
        for (ix = 0; ix < area[i].x.length; ix++) {
            console.log(area[i].x[ix] + ', ' + area[i].y[ix]);
        }
        target = area[i].id;
        break;
     }
}
return target;
}

function pnpoly(nvert, vertx, verty, testx, testy) { //Point in Poly Test http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
var i, j, c = false;
for (i = 0, j = nvert - 1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if (((verty[i] > testy) != (verty[j] > testy)) &&
        (testx < (vertx[j] - vertx[i]) * (testy - verty[i]) / (verty[j] - verty[i]) + vertx[i])) {
        c = !c;
    }
}
return c;
}
```

Basically what it does it is generates an array of objects to represent each 'area' element. These objects have a property for ID, an array of X points and an array of Y points. The draggable items report their center point which is then tested to see if it falls within a certain poly with the point-in-poly function (pnpoly). If a match is found then it returns the ID of the of the area, allowing us to apply logic in the draggable's revert function definition. In this case, I applied a dummy class to represent different acceptable answer types.

Anyway, hopefully that helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you got something like this:

```
<img src="image.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Elements" usemap="#elementmap" />

<map name="elementmap">
  <area id="element1" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Element 1"/>
  <area id="element2" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Element 2"/>
</map>
```

I supposed that you can call `$('#element1')` in your jQuery code to get the object and do something (I think could work because if you put a `click` event that fires an alert in the first element, it works!)

By the other hand, maybe this could help you if you need the coords of the element dropped or just want the element be stablished on a div. Take a look at this example and edit it according to what you need:

Look this first:
http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/

Live example: 
http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop

Finally, a recommendation is not to work 100% with coords because when user resizes browser window, coords change and if you need them in a future time to recover positions and charge all them to the browser, it won't work good.

Obviously I don't know if you need them but I am just saying.

Hope this helps.